# Visual Studio not respecting msbuild schema

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Using Visual Studio 2017, I am trying to conditionally include a project based on the Configuration. I have added a Choose/When in the csproj of the project in question, instead of directly adding a condition on the project reference due to the problem with MSBUILD/Visual Studio integration (see the remark in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild))

However, the build order is not respected when building through visual studio (the solution has been closed and reopened to make sure the Configuration is set).

Has anybody been through this problem?

The choose/when looks like the following:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'MyConfiguration'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Project\MyProject.sqlproj">
          <Name>MyProject</Name>
          <Project>{ece60b8e-84ad-4c4d-94d3-97a1fb1a5d91}</Project>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Project\MyProject2.sqlproj">
          <Name>MyProject2</Name>
          <Project>{ece70c8e-84ad-4c4d-94d3-97a1fb1a5d93}</Project>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>  
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Comment: does the project guid match the one of the referenced projects in both cases?

Comment: @MartinUllrich it does indeed...

Comment: @DOMZE, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I haven't had the time to retry, but I will update this issue with any questions I have and what not. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DOMZE, I look forward to hearing from you:)

Answer (score 0):

> However, the build order is not respected when building through visual studio

I have created a sample with your code snippet, but it works fine on my side. Since there is no build log, I would like provide you some troubleshooting to help you find the reason for this issue.

First, I noticed that you reference different projects from the same project folder `..\Project\..`, Could you confirm that is correct? Have you move the project file `MyProject.sqlproj` and `MyProject2.sqlproj` to the same folder `Project`? If not, please make sure the path of `ProjectReference` is correct, following is my code snippet:

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Test'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.sqlproj">
          <Name>MyProject</Name>
          <Project>{529deb62-9f35-4594-8627-203b19d7cb6d}</Project>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject2\MyProject2.sqlproj">
          <Name>MyProject2</Name>
          <Project>{a6db4708-27d6-40b2-824e-f469372622d9}</Project>
          <Private>True</Private>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
```

Second, make sure the configuration for all projects are the same, for example, my configuration for all projects are `Test`:

[image]

With above condition project reference, the project `MyProject.sqlproj` only build when configuration is `Test`, otherwise, the project `MyProject2.sqlproj` will be built:

[image]

[image]

If above not help you, please share me the build log and what have you done, I will keep follow. Hope this helps.